# Google Apiを使用しgetJSONで結果を受け取りたい

Tags: monaca

MONACAを使用してGoogle APIを使用するプログラムの勉強中です。
$.getJSONで結果を受け取りたいのですが、下記プログラムだとアラートの1.5までしか出ません。
アラート2を表示させるためには、パーミッションとかなにか設定が必要でしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
function getTestAPI(){
alert("1");
  var text1 = $("#Key1").val();
  var url = "https://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=";
  url += encodeURI(text1) + "&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3";
  $("#Page1 #Memo").val($("#Page1 #Memo").val() + "\n" + url );
alert("1.5" + url);

  $.getJSON(url,
    function(data) {
alert("2");
      parseJSON(data);
    }
  );
}
function parseJSON(data){
  alert("3");
}
```